# Can a trait ensure trait bound for parent trait

Tags: rust, traits

A `Base` trait is defined in an external library. I want a new trait that ensures some bound for associated types of `Base` trait

```rust
pub trait Base {
    type T;
    fn get_t() -> Self::T;
}
```

In several codes, I have to write the same where clause `<B as Base>::T: Debug + Display`

```rust
fn base_only<B: Base>()
where
    B::T: Debug + Display,
{
    let t = B::get_t();
    println!("{:?}", t);
}
```

I need to define a trait that ensures trait bonds.

```rust
pub trait DebuggableBase: Base
where
    <Self as Base>::T: Debug + Display,
{
}

impl<B> DebuggableBase for B
where
    B: Base,
    <B as Base>::T: Debug + Display,
{
}
```

but it is still needed the where clause

```rust
fn debug_t<B: DebuggableBase>()
where
    <B as Base>::T: Debug + Display,
{
    let t = B::get_t();
    println!("{:?}", t);
}
```

I expected the definition of `DebuggableBase` that the following code compiles without error:

```rust
fn debug_t<B: DebuggableBase>()
{
    let t = B::get_t();
    println!("{:?}", t);
}
```